# biblatex 3.0+ - bibliography with different sorting schemes but unique labels

Tags: biblatex, numbering, sorting

With biblatex version 2.x or earlier, one can write something like

```
\printbibliography
  [category = cited, sorting = none, title = {References}]
\printbibliography
  [notcategory = cited, sorting = nty, title = {Works Not Cited}]
```

to achieve said effects,
but biblatex 3.0 abolished the `sorting` option of `\printbibliography`,
rendering above-mentioned code invalid.

Following code does not work as expected,
because entry numbers are unconditionally reset
at the beginning of every bibliography context,
and there seems to be no obvious way to turn this off.

```
\begin{refcontext}[sorting = none]
\printbibliography[category = cited, title = {References}]
\end{refcontext}
\begin{refcontext}[sorting = nty]
\printbibliography[notcategory = cited, title = {Works Not Cited}]
\end{refcontext}
```

BTW, this implies that cross-citation inside `\printbibliography`
(eg. changing `title = {Works Not Cited}` to
`title = {Works Not Cited, see also \cite{something}}`,
where `something` is in category `cited`)
no longer works.

So, does there exist an elegant way to achieve the same goal as before?

Comment: @PLK, sorry fot the `@` spam, but do you have any suggestions on this issue?

Comment: Apologies - I missed this - do you have a MWE?

Comment: Never mind; I will use the github issue tracker in case something looking like a bug appears in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These issues should be fixed in biblatex 3.4/biber 2.5 which are now on Sourceforge in the DEV folder. The numbering across refcontexts was a bug and for the cross-bibliography referencing, try it and look at the enhanced documentation about refcontexts and specifically the `\assignrefcontext*` macros - you sometimes have to use these to tell biblatex where to find the data for a citation if the default isn't suitable.

Comment: After installing the dev version, the code that previously did not work now works without modification; the cross-refcontext citation use case in the question (at least seemingly) also works now.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I looked at `\assignrefcontext*`, but did not quite understand; nevertheless the use case in the question now seems able to be addressed without involving these macros.  Thank you all the same :)

Comment: The `\assignrefcontext*` macros are just there to override the default behaviour in cases where you have complicated cross-context citations, usually in situations where citations ambiguously point to more than one bibliography.